# Deriving $ \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty}t^{s-1} e^{-nt} \, dt $ Backwards?

Tags: gamma-function, riemann-zeta

Is it possible to start with $\dfrac{1}{n^s}$ and then, without knowing the Gamma function in advance, naturally (with reasons!) derive that

$$ \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty}t^{s-1} e^{-nt} \, dt $$

*(which comes up when you analyze the Zeta function)*?

I know it can be done by starting from

$$\Gamma(s) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t} \, dt$$

and setting $t = nx$ so that

$$\Gamma(s) = n^s \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-nx} \, dx$$

but working backwards, maybe you can use

$$\frac{1}{n^s} = \int_n^\infty s \frac{dx}{x^{s+1}}$$

and somehow end up at it?

Comment: the change of variable $t= nx$ followed by $y = t/n$ ...

Comment: I guess it's reduced to prove that $n^{s}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s - 1}\,\mathrm{e}^{-nt}\,\,\mathrm{d}t$ satisfies the $Bohr-Mollerup\ Theorem$.

http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.iv

Answer (score 0):

You first line is equivalent to:
$$\mathcal{L}\left(x^{s-1}\right) = \Gamma(s)\,y^{-s} $$
(I used $y$ as a conjugate variable; that is not standard but there are obvious reasons for avoiding $s$) hence the identity "read backwards" deals with:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}(y^{-s})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+\infty} e^{xy} y^{-s}\,dx $$
and the reciprocal $\Gamma$ function makes his appearance (assuming $s\in\mathbb{N}$) as the residue at the origin of $\frac{e^{xy}}{y^s}$.